# How to authenticate in Excel Office Add-In from Microsoft Azure AD

Tags: excel, azure, authentication, add-in, office-addins

I have created an app (Excel Add-In) and deployed on Azure.
Now I want to **enable the Authentication**. In **Excel Office Add-In** it should ask for **Azure user name and password**. After enabling the AD authentication on Azure, it is asking in browser but I need this in Excel.
Please help me to achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: What is your application trying to achieve? You'll need to add the relevant code to your Excel Add-In.

Comment: Its an application provided on Microsoft sample web site. I want to integrate authentication in that application. I want to visit application first page after authentication.

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at these two articles: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/08/10/connecting-to-office-365-from-an-office-add-in/  and https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins. There is also a sample out there on GitHub: https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-API-from-Office-Addin